# Is a doctor obligated to force vaccination?

Tags: halacha, medicine, murder, rodef

As per the injunction of "לא תעמוד על דם רעך" - "Stand not [idly] over the blood of thine fellow"([Leviticus 19:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), is a Torah-observant doctor obligated to vaccinate an unvaccinated patient for a potentially deadly disease, even if that patient and/or that patient's parent/legal guardian is unwilling? Would the patient have the status of a *rodef* (pursuer) whom one is obligated to prevent from committing a murder, by inflicting an injury upon the pursuer?

See also:

- [Maimonides' Laws of Murder 1:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Murderer_and_the_Preservation_of_Life.1.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
- [R' Sternbuch's letter to R' Malkiel Kotler on Vaccination (also in *Teshuvot veHanhagot* 7:176)](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/1631188/rav-moshe-sternbuch-writes-letter-to-rav-malkiel-kotler-about-the-halachic-requirement-to-vaccinate.html)

Comment: I suspect that while anti-vaxxers are wildly incorrect and sinning by not vaccinating, it's probably too indirect to be technically considered a Rodef. Otherwise, just about anything could be stretched into Pikuach Nefesh (i.e. "I have to work on Shabbos, otherwise I might lose my job and not be able to pay my bills and become homeless and starve to death").

Comment: @Salmononius2 Over 500 American Rabbis came out shortly before Pesach signing a letter declaring vaccinating a chiyuv d’Oraisa. I don’t recall if they went so far as to declare them Rodfim, but certainly sinning.

Comment: `Would the patient have the status of a rodef (pursuer) whom one is obligated to prevent from committing a murder, by inflicting an injury upon the pursuer?` You ask for an ill person who is carrier of the virus? The Shut clearly does not address a problem of Rodef. But an ill contagious person can be considered as Rodef. e.g one is AIDS carrier an has intercourse with can be viewed as attempting to kill it and may be Rodef.

Comment: @kouty [HIV carriers]

Comment: The answer cannot possibly be full and general - there are different viruses, predispositions, other deceases, age, place and many more considerations. You must include a premise of certain death if not vacced, otherwise, we should force all Yeshivisher Bochurim into forced sport activities.

Comment: @AlBerko one obvious difference between this and exercising is that if you don't exercise you're only killing yourself, while if you don't vaccinate you're potentially infecting thousands of other people.

Comment: Unintentional rodef is a whole sugya. Another cool one -- R' Asher Weiss shlita referred to unintentional infection (when precautions could have been taken) as *dan dina degarmi*. Is there a din *rodef* for *grama*? For *dina degarmi*?  I'm sure someone's addressed those.

Comment: Define "potentially."  A doctor forcing a dangerous* expedited mRNA vaccine on someone who doesn't need it is the Rodef.    *dangerous supported by "gates-admits-700000-people-may-die-from-his-vaccine" [https://www.armstrongeconomics.com/world-news/corruption/gates-admits-700000-people-may-die-from-his-vaccine/]

Comment: @Shalom Maimonides seems to treat killing of an unborn fetus to save the mother as justified based on the principle of rodef - that it is as if the unborn baby is pursuing the mother.  This would seem to suggest lack of intent may not be a full exemption from the law of rodef.

Comment: @Shalom Furthermore, I believe this is the halacha even if the actual threat to the mother's life is far from certain.

Comment: @DonielF Considering how much has changed since Pesach (with the latest statistics suggesting that 8 out of 10 people who contract the virus never even develop symptoms, let alone die) and a fatality-per-case ratio of [1.7%](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/data/mortality), I wonder how many of those rabbis would still sign such a letter, let alone one that declares someone who refuses to vaccinate a Rodef.

Comment: @Yehuda I posted that comment in 2019, six months before COVID-19 was known to exist and nearly a year before it made its way to America. I believe the context of my comment was regarding the MMR vaccine during the measles outbreak in greater NY Jewish communities at the time.

Comment: @yehuda I'm not sure I fully understand your reasoning - If I vaccinate, no one dies; if I don't vaccinate, I infect a couple of people who each infect a couple of people etc. until many, many people die - why wouldn't those rabbis still sign that letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obviously can't give an opinion on how the following would apply to any specific case, but there are sources which talk about the need to provide medicine to patients, even against their own wishes. Magen Avraham and Kaf Hachaim both cite the Radbaz when saying that one can force a patient to take medicine even if the patient doesn't want to. These opinions are independent of the patient being a rodef - they are all based simply on the patient's own well being. The Rambam likewise says that one is not allowed to [risk one's own life unnecessarily](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Murderer_and_the_Preservation_of_Life.11.5?lang=bi).

- [Magen Avraham 328:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.328.6?)

  אם לא רצה החולה לקבל התרופה כופין אותו, חולה אומר צריך אני לתרופה פלונית ורופא אומר א"צ שומעין לחולה ואם הרופא אומר שאותו תרופה יזיקהו שומעין לרופא [רדב"ז ח"א ס"ו כ"ה]:

  If the patient does not want the medicine, we force the patient to take it. If the patient says he requires a certain medicine, and the doctor says the patient does not need it, we listen to the patient. If the doctor says that that medicine will harm [the patient], we listen to the doctor.
- [Kaf HaChaim 328:45](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.328.45.1?lang=bi)

  שם. כל חולי שהרופאים אומרים וכו' ואם לא רצה החולה לאכול או לעשות תרופה משום מדת חסידות כופין אותו לעשות. הרדב"ז ח"א סי' ס"ו, כנה"ג בהגה"ט. מ"א סק"ו. ר"ז או' י"א. ח"א כלל ס"ח או' ח'.

  If the patient does not want to eat or receive medicine because of a matter of piety, [the patient] is forced to do so.

Regarding parents, the same basic principle applies. The Radbaz has a relevant teshuva. A baby was 2 years old and was still very weak. The baby would be potential danger if it was weaned. It would not nurse from anyone other than it's mother, so a wet nurse wasn't a viable option. The Radbaz suggests a number of options, but ultimately concludes that even if the woman wants to stop nursing, she can be forced to continue nursing because it is important to the babies health. ([Teshuvot HaRadbaz 1:349](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_1.349) - I believe this is the one the acharonim above are referring to and either their citation system is something unfamiliar to me or the numbers of the Teshuvot are printed differently in their edition compared to the probably more modern edition digitized by Sefaria).

Although the above answers your question without needing to resort to calling someone a rodef, it is an interesting question. I haven't seen anyone who explicitly says this, however, [Rav Aviner comes fairly close](http://shlomo-aviner.net/index.php?title=%D7%A9%D7%95%22%D7%AA_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8)). He does say that there is an obligation to vaccinate and dismisses the notion that one has the freedom to chose not to vaccinate. He also says that a non-vaccinator can be considered a rodef.

> ש: האם חייבים להתחסן?
>
> ת: כן. ונשמרתם מאוד לנפשותיכם. "הרבה דברים אסרו חכמים מפני שיש בהם
> סכנת נפשות. וכל העובר עליהן ואומר: הריני מסכן בעצמי ומה לאחרים עלי בכך
> או איני מקפיד בכך, מכין אותו מכת מרדות" (רמב"ם, הלכות רוצח ושמירת נפש
> יא ה).
>
> ש: במדינות מודרניות יש חירות הפרט לעשות כרצונו אם לחסן.
>
> ת: א. החירות האמיתית היא לשמור תורה ומצוות. ב. אין לו חרות לסכן ילדיו
> שיחלו בגלל שלא חיסן אותם. ג. הוא גם מסכן אחרים שעלולים להידבק ממנו,
> ויש בזה משום דין רודף.

> Q: Is one obligated to vaccinate?
>
> A: Yes. 'For your own sake be careful' (Devarim 4:15). Many things
> were forbidden by the sages since they caused mortal danger. Anyone
> who violates this and says 'I am putting myself in danger, what do
> other care?' or 'I will be careful' We give him [rabbinic] lashes  (Rambam).
>
> Q: In modern countries, we have some freedom to do as we wish with
> vaccinations.
>
> A: 1) Real freedom is to guard the Torah and mitzvot. 2) One has no
> freedom to endanger one's children that they should become ill because he did not vaccinate them. 3)
> he is also endangering others that may be infected by him, and there is in this
> the law of rodef (the pursuer).

Comment: +1  I tweaked the translations a bit. E.g. the rabbinic nature of makat mardus just means the lashes are not biblically mandated, not that the prohibition itself isn't biblical. Also, it does sound, at least based on the cited language, that Rav Aviner does indeed maintain an antivaxxer is a form of rodef.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose, theoretically, that forcibly vaccinating a patient who doesn't want it is akin to pulling someone out of the way of a speeding car when they intended to get hit; and let's suppose that both are akin to saving someone who was endangered by accident and had no intention of self-harm. (All of those are big *if*s.)

Even then, there's plenty of halachic discussion on the *cost incurred* to get up and save a life. (The Talmud says to save someone's property I'm not expected to incur loss -- if I watch his lost ox, I can and should use the ox while I feed it. Whereas to save someone's life or limb, I should *rent* equipment if needed. It doesn't say "spend", it says "rent." The commentaries there assume the language -- normally the alternative to *begufo* is *bemamono*, but here it's *leradia* -- implies you may seek to be repaid afterwards.)

I'd imagine a doctor could lose his/her license, or even be criminally charged, by forcing any kind of medicine on a patient. At that point we do have a similar question addressed in the halachic literature -- suppose a doctor discovers a patient has AIDS, knows about it, and tells his doctor explicitly: *my fiancee doesn't know about this, she's naive, I intend to keep hiding this from her, and not use protection; I don't care if she gets it from me.* If there was no cost to the doctor, *don't stand by* would obligate him or her to speak up. (Practically, appropriate mechanisms allow for just that -- the doctor could take it to the hospital's ethics panel.) But if the only way to do so would mean the doctor could be fired or worse ... there's a lot of discussion on that one; it's likely considered a cost too high.

Comment: The question's "Would the patient have the status of a _rodef_" means it's primarily thinking of others' welfare, not the patient's; the answer primarily addresses the patient's.

Comment: @msh210 even so -- I'm only expected to go so far to fulfill *lo saamod*; the infected fellow breathing on others should be akin to the HIV-positive guy about to get married and not use protection (with his wife totally unaware of the danger). While you want to protect her, you're not obligated to take measures that will end with you in jail.

Comment: where are these?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying - the biblical prohibition of "*lo saamod al dam reyecha*" is negated by one's need to keep his/her job?!  Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Loewian any *asei* requires you to only spend a fifth of your assets. The Gemara doesn't say you have to *lose* money to save a life, only to lose liquidity.

Comment: so you're speculating that one need not expend more on this lav then one does on an esrog? The linked rambam doesn't imply such a limit at all.  Do you have any source to support this assertion?

Answer (score 1):

The first  question is if  giving vaccines to someone who is currently healthy has the halachic status of  Pikuach Nefesh and Lo Saamid Al Dam Rayach . While it is possible someone will  die and cause others to die as a result of their failure to vaccinate that possibly also exists with driving a car. A serious epidemic would be a situation of pikuach nefesh where one can be required to administer vaccines. One can even give them on Shabbos if there will be no other opportunity  to do so but not all vaccines are given for such heavy risks. When a risk enters the category of potential pikuach nefesh is a complicated question of it's own.

When it comes to  forcing vaccines on people when there is no  epidemic serious enough to to make this vaccine clearly be considered pikuach nefesh   there are differences in opinion. The Nishmas Avrohom (Choshen Mishpat 426b and 427a) says  that parents (and by extension doctors) cannot be forced to vaccinate their healthy children, even if the parent is refusing  because of an "irrational
fear". While others are of the opinions that parents must vaccinate that would be relevant to *parents*. What obligation is there on a doctor to give a vaccine against someone's will anymore than giving any other  treatment for a nonpaying patient?(It's safe to assume someone being vaccinated against his will isn't going to pay for it) Shulchan Aruch (Y.D. 336:3)discusses doctors (over)charging and the obligation to pay afterwards. The Rema says that even though a doctor has a  mitzvah to treat this patient, it is not a mitzvah incumbent specifically on him.  Theoretically anyone can become a doctor and heal people. Therefore no doctor has a personal obligation to treat people over anyone else. (note: Rashi gives the refusal to heal the poor for free as one the reason the Mishna says "Tov S'b'Rofim L'Gehenim)

If a doctor can refuse treatment over money he presumably  can do so because the patient is also unwilling to accept it.

Ask your Rav if you are a doctor. None of the above is meant halacha l'maashe.